# Vue module not found import

Tags: vue.js

So I want to import but it always show `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/resources/js/services/http/Http' in 'D:\laragon\www\myapp\resources\js\pages\posts'` how do I need to import this? Structure:
[image]

Inside `Manage.vue` importing like this `import { Http } from '/resources/js/services/http/Http';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the root folder is the `'js'` folder. So you are basically referencing this path: `js/resources/js/services/http/Http.js`

You should be importing with the base folder ( again `'js'`) in mind.

```
import { Http }  from './services/http/Http.js';
```

In your case you are trying to import your module from inside the pages/posts directory, that is why you should import your module like this:

```
import { Http }  from '../../services/http/Http.js';
```

Comment: I have edited my answer a bit, so it answers your specific problem a little bit better.